# How to sort TreeMap alphabetically if first char is "+" or "-"

Tags: java, treemap, sortedmap

I have map looks like this

**key:** `+ something`
**value:** `something`

So it have a big amount of strings starting with `+` or `-`, and I need to sort it alphabetically.

For example:

```
{
  host: hexlet.io,
+ timeout: 20,
+ verbose: true,
- follow: false,
- proxy: 123.234.53.22,
- timeout: 50
}
```

And it must be sorted to this:

```
{
- follow: false,
  host: hexlet.io,
- proxy: 123.234.53.22,
- timeout: 50,
+ timeout: 20,
+ verbose: true
}
```

How can I sort it skipping "+" or "-"?

UPD:

Thx so much! But i missed out that my boileplate must be kinda of this:
(it contains 2 whitespace before minus and 1 whitespace after it)

```
{
  - follow: false
    host: hexlet.io
  - proxy: 123.234.53.22
  - timeout: 50
  + timeout: 20
  + verbose: true
}
```

So if i make s -> s.substring(2) it doesn`t sort it alphabetically, or if i use 3-4, my "timeout" string crashes, i have "+ timeout: 50" instead of "-timeout: 50" and "+ timeout: 20".
How can i fix it?

Comment: you should use the custom Comparator.
and please don't use pictures - format the code

Comment: `Comparator.comparing(s -> s.substring(2))`

Comment: Thx so much! And sorry for incorrect pictures!

Comment: Copy & paste 3 things __as text__ here (so we can copy and try on our side: (1) the strings unsorted, (2) the strings sorted like you want, (3) your Java attempts as [example] .

Comment: The usual best answer to questions of this sort is _don't use some downstream textual representation, use the native data structure_. In this case that looks like a diff of some sort.

Comment: It must be just sort alphabetically, i don`t care how "+" or "-" goes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can create a `TreeMap` with a custom `Comparator` and then use `putAll` to add all elements from an existing map to the sorted implementation.

According to the example, custom comparator needs to include two parts:

1. check if the key starts with `"  + "` and put it to the end, assuming that strings starting with `"  - "` or with empty prefix `"  "` should be treated the same
2. compare "substring" version of the key when needed without the prefix.

For example:

```java
Map<String, Object> data = Map.of(
    "    host", "hexlet.io",
    "  + timeout", 20,
    "  + verbose", true,
    "  - follow", false,
    "  - proxy", "123.234.53.22",
    "  - timeout", 50
);
String plusPrefix = "  + ";

Map<String, Object> sorted = new TreeMap<>(
  Comparator.comparing((String str) -> str.startsWith(plusPrefix) ? 1 : -1)
            .thenComparing(str -> str.substring(plusPrefix.length()))
);
sorted.putAll(data);
System.out.println("{");
sorted.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v));
System.out.println("}");
```

Output (sorted in the requested order):

```
{
  - follow: false
    host: hexlet.io
  - proxy: 123.234.53.22
  - timeout: 50
  + timeout: 20
  + verbose: true
}
```

Comment: Can you check UPD please?

Comment: As it stands, this fails when `"- host", "obj"` is a K/V pair.  It considers `host` a duplicate key and overwrites the existing one.

Comment: @k0dama1337, I provided the update with better handling of the prefixes, also I assumed  that `host` also has an "empty" prefix of 4 spaces,